# Expected value of the following players’ scores?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, expected-value

> Players A and B, each starting with a score of zero, continuously roll a d6 until a 6 is rolled, with player A starting first. Each player’s rolls are added to their individual scores (including the 6). What are the expected values of a) the total scores of A and B, b) A’s score, c) B’s score?

What I know is that the total score is independent of what A and B roll, and can be treated as an individual player continuously rolling until a 6 is obtained. The recursion relation is $5\mathbb{E}(X)+21=6\mathbb{E}(X)$ so $\mathbb{E}(X)=21$. I also know that by linearity of expectation the sum of the expected values of A and B’s scores should be 21. However I am unsure of how to obtain A’s score. I do know the answer is $126/11$ but I do not know what my recursion relation looks like. Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v_A$ and $v_B$ be the expected value of the game for Player $A$ and $B$, respectively.
Let
$$
v\equiv\begin{pmatrix}v_{A}\\
v_{B}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
A turn is comprised of two rolls, one from Player $A$ and one from Player $B$.
On each turn, one of three things can occur: (*i*) the game can stop because Player $A$ rolled a six, (*ii*) the game can stop because Player $B$ rolled a six, or (*iii*) none of the above, in which case the game continues.
Therefore, the expected value can be represented as a sum of three terms:
$$
v=\frac{1}{6}\begin{pmatrix}6\\
0
\end{pmatrix}+\frac{1}{36}\sum_{1\leq i\leq 5}\begin{pmatrix}i\\
6
\end{pmatrix}+\frac{1}{36}\sum_{1\leq i,j\leq 5}\left(\begin{pmatrix}i\\
j
\end{pmatrix}+v\right).
$$
Simplifying,
$$
\left(1-\frac{25}{36}\right)v=\begin{pmatrix}7/2\\
35/12
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Dividing both sides by the coefficient of $v$ above,
$$
v=\begin{pmatrix}126/11\\
105/11
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
From the above, $v_A = 126/11$, $v_B=105/11$, and $v_A+v_B=21$.

Comment: A good check is that we expect it to take $6$ rolls to get a $6$ and the average roll is $3.5$, so the expected sum is $21$.